# tensorboard: command not found, when I use

Tags: python, tensorflow

I already use python IDE PyCharm and have installed the package tensorflow but when I use the terminal and give an input to the tensor board as follows
`--logdir = '/user/....'`，
it shows command not found?

is  there still something Im missing like setting the tenor flow path or any thing else?

Comment: I understand my answer helped. Can you maybe accept? that's the way SO works to everyone's benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to activate your relevant environment via `source activate some_conda_env`.
If it isn't either of those you're going to need to give more information than you've given in the question (versions, environment, etc.)

---

Update (due to discussion in comments):
It seems that `tensorboard` is not in your search path.
That can be fixed, but meanwhile you can just run tensorboard by using the full path. e.g.  `/my/full/path/to/tensorboard --logdir='/path/to/logger'` etc.
Good luck!

Comment: yes, it is a typo, I mean to run tensorboard and tensor ,it's same to shows command not found

Comment: Did you try the other option? Did you check if you've got tensorboard in your paths list via `which tensorboard`? Do you know where in your python installation or conda environments you have tensorboard?

Comment: source activate some_conda_env? I am not installed condo,just use PyCharm install the tensorflow and it works well in PyCharm ,

Comment: Ok, then where are your installed modules located?

Comment: it's in  '/Users/anyongyi/PycharmProjects/JD/venv/bin/tensorboard'，and I already the path to  base_profile, and it's still not work

Comment: try run it with the full path. /Users/anyongyi/PycharmProjects/JD/venv/bin/tensorboard --log-dir etc...

Comment: oh yes, it worded now when I use "/Users/anyongyi/PycharmProjects/JD/venv/bin/tensorboard --logdir = '/Users/anyongyi/Desktop/test/ "

Comment: Then it's not in your search path :-)
But that's a different question regarding linux or whatever, not tensorboard. I'll edit my answer so you can accept. Good luck!